# lipschitz boundary from the polar parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, lipschitz-functions, parametrization

I take  $A$  open boundd subset in$\quad \mathbb{R^2}$ and I take the polar parametrization of $A$:
$x(\theta)=  R(\theta) cos(\theta)$.
$y(\theta)=  R(\theta)sin(\theta)$.$\quad$
$\theta \in [0,2\pi]$

what is the condition on $R$ to make the boundary of A lipschtizien ?

Comment: I hope you have $R(0) = R(2\pi)$? Also, this should be the parametrization of the _boundary_ of $A$.

Comment: yes @amsmath we have this